# Dell N4110 touchpad suddenly stopped working

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, touchpad, dell

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit and my touchpad on Dell N4110 suddenly stopped working.

I have checked the **mouse and touchpad** settings and the touchpad is not disabled. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, my problem is not exactly yours, it stops suddenly and when I restart it works again, this occurs occasionally.
Solution worked for me is this code:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit also on my Samsung RC512 laptop and my touchpad (along with the buttons) also stopped working around the same date as Jorge. I did install some updates recently. I suspect an update was the cause.

Also, suspend is no longer working properly. The screen will dim but the power and other lights on the laptop will not turn off and the power supply will not turn off.

Anyone else encounter this or find a fix yet?